# Display vertically an embedded combo chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to display a bar chart combined to a line using an EmbeddedComboChartBuilder.
For this I'm using the following code and data:

```
function createChartSerie() {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX...');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
    
    var chartTableXRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A24");
    var chartTableYRange = sheet.getRange("B1:C24");
      
    var chart = sheet.newChart()
      .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
      .setOption('hAxis', {
          title: 'X',
          format: '#,##'
        })
        .setOption('vAxes', {0: {
          title: 'Y', format: '#,##'
        }})
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
        .addRange(chartTableXRange) // x axis
        .addRange(chartTableYRange) //first y data
        .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
        .setOption('orientation', 'vertical')
        .setOption('series', {
        0: {
          type: 'line', 
          color: 'red'
        },
        1: {
          type: 'bars', 
          color: 'blue'
        }
      })
        .build();
    
    sheet.insertChart(chart);
    }
```

The data range used to display the combo chart:

```
A   B   C
1   0.0001  0
1.5 0.0009  0.0006
2   0.0044  0.0037
2.5 0.0175  0.0133
3   0.054   0.0236
3.5 0.1296  0.0533
4   0.242   0.0073
4.5 0.3522  0.2468
5   0.399   0.0843
5.5 0.3522  0.3352
6   0.242   0.2201
6.5 0.1296  0.0607
7   0.054   0.0256
7.5 0.0175  0.0006
8   0.0044  0.003
8.5 0.0009  0.0005
9   0.0001  0.0001
```

It seems that the option  **.setOption('orientation', 'vertical')** has no effect as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

This option is working well when using with google visualization like you can see in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0me4vqs2/).

Comment: Isn't it `vertical` instead of `verticale`?

Comment: It's 'vertical' you are right but that doesn't change anything. I have corrected my example code.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889129/5090771)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Unfortunately Sheets API does not support this option ([see the embedded charts resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts)).

There seems to be a [feature request in Google’s Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/177824514). You can click the white start (☆) so Google knows that you want this to be done.

### Workarounds

There are 2 workarounds: use Google Charts itself on a web (works with WebApps and modals), and generate the chart with Google Charts, convert the SVG on the page to PNG and embed that to the spreadsheet. Generating a PNG requires making a modal, so this set instructions will work for both workarounds.

#### Step 1: Make a page that uses Google Charts to make a chart

Get some mocking data and make your chart, design it to your taste, and make sure everything works fine.

#### Step 2: Show it using a modal

Add a new HTML file named `Chart` (you can change the name but you’ll need to change it in the code) and paste the code you made.

Once you have a mock chart, we need to show it using a modal. We first need to add a menu to the spreadsheet:

```js
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .createMenu('Chart generator')
   .addItem('Create and insert chart', 'showChart')
   .addToUi()
}
```

Then we add the function that shows the modal:

```js
function showChart() {
 const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Chart')
   .setWidth(900)
   .setHeight(600)
 
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Chart')
}
```

You can also set up a WebApp with the same template:

```js
function doGet(e) {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Chart')
  .setWidth(900)
  .setHeight(600)
}
```

#### Step 3: Get the data from the spreadsheet

Now it’s time to remove the mock data and get the actual data. To do this we’ll use the `google.script.run` function to asynchronously load the data. This example uses asynchronous logic so it can load the charts library and the data in parallel.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})
const readyPromise = toAsync(resolve => google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(resolve))
const dataPromise = toAsync((resolve, reject) => {
 google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(resolve)
   .withFailureHandler(reject)
   .getData()
})
```

`toAsync` is a helper function that makes sure to reject if there is an error that’s not handled by a failure callback:

```js
function toAsync(callback) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   try {
     callback(resolve, reject)
   } catch(e) {
     reject(e)
   }
 })
}
```

Then we need to add the function in Google Apps Script that actually reads the data from the spreadsheet:

```js
function getData() {
 return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
   .getRange('A1:C18')
   .getValues()
}
```

Then simply use both in the main function:

```js
async function drawVisualization() {
 const el = document.getElementById('chart_div')
 
 await readyPromise
 const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(await dataPromise)
 const options = { … }
 new google.visualization.ComboChart(el).draw(data, options)
}
```

Make sure that the call handles the promise rejection otherwise you may silence errors unknowingly:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => drawVisualization().catch(console.error))
```

#### (Optional) Step 4: Embedding chart as PNG

Google Charts generate SVGs. Unfortunately we cannot embed a SVG so we need to convert it to a PNG. The easiest way to do it is using an external library like `canvg` which allows us to draw an SVG into a canvas. Then we can export the canvas as PNG.

Add a canvas to your body and the library to your head.

Then you can draw on the canvas using (append to `drawVisualization`):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
v = canvg.Canvg.fromString(ctx, el.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].outerHTML)
v.start()
await v.ready()
```

This will draw it and wait until it’s done.

Now we need a way of sending the generated image to GAS so it can embed it. Thankfully we can get a base64 of the PNG and send it to there:

```js
const base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(';base64,')[1]
 
await toAsync((resolve, reject) => {
 google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(resolve)
   .withFailureHandler(reject)
   .insertChart(base64)
})
```

And in Google Apps Script, we define `insertChart`:

```js
function insertChart(base64png) {
 const blob = Utilities.newBlob(
   Utilities.base64Decode(base64png,  Utilities.Charset.US_ASCII),
   'image/png',
   'chart.png'
 )
 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
   .insertImage(blob, 5, 5, 0, 0)
}
```

#### (Optional) Step 5: Close modal and hide charts while being generated

Now that it’s being inserted, I like to automatically close the modal. To do so just append this to `drawVisualization`:

```js
google.script.host.close()
```

I also like to not show the chart while being processed. A bit of CSS should be enough:

```css
canvas, #chart_div {
 visibility: hidden;
}
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

You cannot use `display: none` because then it will generate charts of the wrong size. Overflow is set to avoid the scroll bars into nothing.

You can also change the screen title and even a loading animation to the modal.

### References

- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Serve HTML as a Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms user interface (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms_user_interface)
- [HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename)
- [Serve HTML as a web app (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_web_app)
- [google.script.run (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Range getValues() (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Utilities.newBlob(data, contentType, name) (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata,-contenttype,-name)
- [Utilities.base64Decode(encoded, charset) (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded,-charset)
- [Sheet insertImage(blobSource, column, row) (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row)
- [google.script.host close() (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close)
- [Canvas toDataURL (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
- [Promise (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)